# React Semantic UI - Sticky Sidebar

Tags: semantic-ui, sidebar, semantic-ui-react

Is there any way to use `react-semantic-ui`'s `<Sidebar>` to have a sticky sidebar?

One way to achieve the sticky behavior is to just skip and not use `<Sidebar.Pushable>`, but then I can't use `<Sidebar.Pusher>`'s `dimmed` prop.

Other than the method I stated above, I found no other method that's not too hacky.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this a while back. Here is how I did it:

#### my-sidebar.css:

```
.pushable {
  height: auto;
}
.pushable > .pusher {
  min-height: fit-content;
}
```

It was long time ago so let me know if it didn't work so I can update this.

Answer (score 0):

**Sticky with sidebar**

I wanted to have a sticky error message overflowing the content with a vertical sidebar pushable on the left.

I tried for hours with sticky but I have not been able to make it.

The cleanest solution I found is to use Portal and to add css to push it at the top.

This is my message component (next to the pushable sidebar)

```
    class AppAlert extends React.Component{

    getColor(){
        return 'green';
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <TransitionablePortal open={true} transition={{ animation: 'swing down', duration:1000 }} closeOnDocumentClick={false}>
                <Sidebar style={{position: 'fixed', top: '0'}} direction="top" animation="overlay">
                    <Message color={this.getColor()}>
                        My message<br/>
                        My message<br/>
                        My message<br/>
                    </Message>
                </Sidebar>
          </TransitionablePortal>
        )
    }
}

export default AppAlert;
```

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll7Ng.png)